# Child grows only in one direction (downward) due to parent padding. Text moves down on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code (2nd demo) and the working code (1st demo) are literally the same, but I think what's happening with the hover effect in my code is that the parent element's padding is respected, and the child is not allowed to grow upward in height. Why doesn't this happen with the 1st demo (orange background), and how can I fix mine? Note that the borders are added for debugging.

Edit: I have found the cause. It is due to the float:left in .menu a.
Can anyone explain why? I know float:left places the element along the left side of the container, but why does this create the undesired effect below? I can't come up with an explanation for why one implies the other.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
div {
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Raleway;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#nav-3 {
  background: #EEA200;
}

.link-3 {
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;

}
.link-3:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #EEA200;
  padding: 24px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-3">
    <a class="link-3" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="link-3" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="link-3" href="#">Contact</a>
    <a class="link-3" href="#">Shop</a>
</div>
```

```css
.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #008b10;
}


.menu {

padding: 16px;
text-align:center;
font-family: Raleway, arial, sans-serif;
float:left;
overflow: visible;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

 .menu a:hover {

background-color: #ffffff;
color: #008b10;
padding: 16px 5px;

}

.menu a {
/*box-sizing: border-box;*/
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
transition: 0.4s;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 5px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class=header>
        <div class="menu">
            <a class="help" href="#" id="online_help">Help</a>
            <a class="logout" href="#" onclick="openLogout();">Logout</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
  background-color: #008b10;
}


.menu {
padding: 16px;
text-align:center;
font-family: Raleway, arial, sans-serif;
overflow: visible;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

.menu a {
text-decoration: none;
transition: 0.4s;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 5px;
margin: 0 10px;
}
.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #008b10;
  padding: 16px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class=header>
        <div class="menu">
            <a class="help" href="#" id="online_help">Help</a>
            <a class="logout" href="#" onclick="openLogout();">Logout</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Just because float:left specify the element placed along the left side of the container.